# How to compile scss at runtime from public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

In order to compile additional css assets from theme folder inside the public dir I added the following to assets.rb (rails 5.1)

```
#assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("public", "themes", "default")
```

inside a view (haml) which is also located in the public dir I have this include:

```
# public/layouts/default.html.haml
%link{:href => "/themes/default/sdk.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
```

The sdk.css

```
/*
 *= require self
 *= require bootstrap/bootstrap
 */
```

Surprisingly this scss file is not getting compiled. The output in the browser is exactly the same:

```
/*
 *= require self
 *= require bootstrap/bootstrap
 */
```

Another try was using the style_sheet helper like this:

```
 = stylesheet_link_tag 'sdk.scss'
```

The file is getting served, but uncompiled.

So how can I compile scss assets at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed from the code you included:

1. Your file is not an .scss file (it is a .css file), so no compilation is necessary.
2. Your link is looking in the /themes/default/sdk.css path, but you've specified /public/themes/default/sdk.css as the place where the css file resides.  Therefore, your path appears to be incorrect, which would cause your css file not to load.

Comment: renaming it to scss causes a 404 http://localhost:3000/themes/default/sdk.css . I can load it as http://localhost:3000/themes/default/sdk.scss but again it does not compile. I ommit  the public folder since it is not needed for assets in inside the public folder right? If I do prepend it, again a 404

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it myself with a helper from rails

```
 = stylesheet_link_tag 'sdk'
```

Can anyone tell me why the relative include does not work in this case?

```
%link{:href => "/themes/default/sdk.scss", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
```